# Saving href as js var

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following:

```
<a class="link" href="#to_something">Something</a>
```

Now, how do I save the `href` as js var?

```
var link = jQuery(this).find('.link').???();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need this.

```
var link = jQuery(this).find('.link').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below.

```
var link = $('.link').attr('href');
```

Comment: Thanks! =) forgot about `attr`

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's attribute getter [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var link = jQuery(this).find('.link').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var strLinkHref =  $("a.link").attr("href");
   alert(strLinkHref) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="http://www.google.com">Simple Link</a>
```